# Simplicity for executing Java from C++

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, user-interface, java-native-interface

*Background info*: I am used to program in Java and I know how to use Eclipse and Visual Studio.

*Final objective*: to create a GUI, preferably in Visual Studio, which executes Java functions.

*What I wish to accomplish from this question*: a button in C++ which, on click, executes a Java function and returns the results to C++. (probably by invoking a JVM)

I've currently considered the following datastructures:

- Sharing data through 'common' files such as .txt files (but then how do I start the Java functions?)
- Opening a socket (seems too complicated for this problem)
- Connecting through a server (too complicated)
- Invoking a JVM from C++ which then executes the Java file (I think this is the most reasonable way but this needs a lot of code)

Now I know about the existence of `Jace`, `JNI` and `SWIG` but I think they are very handy for making complicated programs, not easy interfaces. I don't want to make a complicated program hence I feel that learning all their commands is quite bothersome.

I have also read up on a lot of Stack Exchange questions asking the exact same thing but all of them seem to give very complicated answers.

So here is my question:

**What is the absolute simplest way to execute a (if necessary: precompiled) Java function from C++ where the C++ code passes some arguments to this Java function**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second question is addressed by many questions in SO. This question links to some of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe . (Personally, I use exe4j.)

Comment: Yes, I've read about those questions as well. But this will make my Java function executable, not render a 'good' (Visual C++ good) interface along with it.

Comment: Right. You asked about making an executable file from your Java code in the next-to-last paragraph above.

Comment: "interface comparable to what Visual C++ can do"—do you mean like [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) does?

Comment: It is “Visual Studio”, not “Virtual Studio”...

Comment: Judging by `System::Object^` you are talking about c++/cli (which is not c++), right?

Comment: @TomBlodget: SWT seems like a good alternatieve but this will make a sort of applet or not? Is it possible to make an (independent?) executable file from this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689/java-and-c-sharp-interoperability - maybe this can help? The jni4net library?

Comment: @n0rd: I haven't heard of this `jni4net` before. I will look into it tomorrow. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I will update my question if this, indeed, results in a very easy implementable answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Invoking a JVM from C++ which then executes the Java file (I think this is the most reasonable way but this needs a lot of code)

Yes, it definitely is the most reasonable way. And with JNI and the [invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502) it's not even that much code.

## Finding the jvm.dll

You could try things like hardcoding the path to the Oracle JVM's `jvm.dll` or searching for a file called `jvm.dll` in the programs folder, but all that is obviously extremely hacky. However, there is apparently a pretty easy solution: The registry. The key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment` contains a `REG_SZ` called `CurrentVersion`. You can read the value of this key (currently it's `1.7`) and open a child key with that name (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7` in this example). That key will then contain a `REG_SZ` called `RuntimeLib` which is the path to your `jvm.dll`. Don't worry about `Program files` vs `Program files (x86)`. WOW64 will automatically redirect your registry query to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` if you're a 32bit process on a 64bit windows and that key contains the path to the 32 bit `jvm.dll`. Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <jni.h> // C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10\include\jni.h

// ...

DWORD retval;
// fetch jvm.dll path from registry
HKEY jKey;
if (retval = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment"), 0, KEY_READ, &jKey))
{
    RegCloseKey(jKey);
    // assuming you're using C++/CLI
    throw gcnew System::ComponentModel::Win32Exception(retval);
}

TCHAR versionString[16]; // version numbers shouldn't be longer than 16 chars
DWORD bufsize = 16 * sizeof(TCHAR);
if (retval = RegGetValue(jKey, NULL, TEXT("CurrentVersion"), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, versionString, &bufsize))
{
    RegCloseKey(jKey);
    // assuming you're using C++/CLI
    throw gcnew System::ComponentModel::Win32Exception(retval);
}

TCHAR* dllpath = new TCHAR[512];
bufsize = 512 * sizeof(TCHAR);
retval = RegGetValue(jKey, versionString, TEXT("RuntimeLib"), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, dllpath, &bufsize)
RegCloseKey(jKey);
if (retval)
{
    delete[] dllpath;
    // assuming you're using C++/CLI
    throw gcnew System::ComponentModel::Win32Exception(retval);
}
```

### Loading the jvm.dll and getting the CreateJavaVM function

This part is pretty straightforward, you just use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`:

```
HMODULE jniModule = LoadLibrary(dllpath);
delete[] dllpath;
if (jniModule == NULL)
    throw gcnew System::ComponentModel::Win32Exception();
typedef int (JNICALL * JNI_CreateJavaVM)(JavaVM** jvm, JNIEnv** env, JavaVMInitArgs* initargs);
JNI_CreateJavaVM createJavaVM = (JNI_CreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(jniModule, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
```

### Creating the JVM

Now you can invoke that function:

```
JavaVMInitArgs initArgs;
initArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
initArgs.nOptions = 0;
JavaVM* jvm;
JNIEnv* env;
if ((retval = createJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &initArgs)) != JNI_OK)
    throw gcnew System::Exception(); // beyond the scope of this answer
```

Congratulations! There's now a JVM running right inside your process! You would probably launch the JVM at the startup of your application. Unless you are 100% **sure** that you will only ever invoke Java code from the thread that just created the JVM, you can throw away the `env` pointer, but you have to keep the `jvm` pointer.

### Getting the JNI environment (optional)

So now you created the JVM and your application is up and running and then somebody clicks that button. Now you want to invoke Java code. If you are 100% **sure** that you are right now on the thread that created the JVM in the previous step and you still have the `env` pointer, then you can skip this. Otherwise, perform a quick check if the current thread is attached to the JVM and attach it if it isn't:

```
JNIEnv* env;
bool mustDetach = false;
jint retval = jvm->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
if (retval == JNI_EDETACHED)
{
    JavaVMAttachArgs args;
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.name = NULL;
    args.group = NULL;
    retval = jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, &args);
    mustDetach = true; // to clean up afterwards
}
if (retval != JNI_OK)
    throw gcnew System::Exception(); // should never happen
invokeJavaCode(env); // next step
if (mustDetach)
    jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

### Invoking Java code

Now you are right there, you want to invoke that Java code and you even have the `env` pointer. You want the easiest solution, so this is how you call a static method:

```
jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/myself/MyClass");
if (clazz == NULL)
    throw gcnew System::Exception();
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "myStaticMethod", "<signature>");
if (mid == NULL)
    throw gcnew System::Exception();
<type> returnedValue = env->CallStatic<type>Method(clazz, mid, <arguments>);
```

You can use `javap -s` (command line tool) to determine a method's signature. `<type>` can be any primitive type (it must match the return type of the Java method). The arguments can be of any primitive type, as long as they match the arguments of the Java method.

### The end

And there you have it: The easiest way to invoke Java code from C++ on Windows (actually only the first two parts are windows-specific...). Oh, and also the most efficient one. Screw databases and files. Using `127.0.0.1` sockets would be an option but that's significantly less efficient and probably not less work than this. Wow, this answer is a bit longer than I expected. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: This answer is amazing! You totally answered my question and clearly elaborated on every step! Thank you very much!